# Android build error due to incorrect java version

Tags: java, android, build

I am currently trying to build Android just for learning purpose. But I am facing strange error -

> You are attempting to build with the incorrect version of java.   Your
>   version is: java version "1.7.0_07". The correct version is: Java SE
>   1.6.

my java - version gives me

> java version "1.7.0_07" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_07-b10) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

any Idea what went wrong?
regards,

Comment: btw, from the google initializing page for building the source ->
**JDK 6 if you wish to build Gingerbread or newer;**
does that mean it will take exactly 1.6 not newer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open jdk is not supported for android build. Try using sun jdk instead. You can install sun jdk by these commands:

```
add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
apt-get update
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

If the above command does not work(fails to download jdk), use the following    commands instead:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
apt-get update
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Comment: I already installed sun-jdk 6 update 27
but the build is now failing due to some other errors

Comment: can you please post the error...is it the same one you posted above?

Comment: no actually builder fails to find java if only openjdk is installed (by default)

Comment: This doesn't seem true in 2018, the official android doc says you should use openjdk 8 in Ubuntu >= 15.04:

https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing

Answer (score 17):

1.) If you’ve already installed OpenJDK . Remove it by running this command:
`sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`

2.) Then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3.) Select which version you want
To install Oracle Java 8:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To install Oracle Java 7:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

To install the Java 6:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

Answer (score 4):

After upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 - just export path before build Android e.g:

export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/:$PATH

Comment: open-jdk is not supported by android build ... I guess this method won't work

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse.. Goto Window -> Preferences.. from there Expand the "Java" group. Click "Compiler". From there set the compiler compliance level to 1.6 and all other settings (if not already set to use the default compliance level) to 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the message says... Android requires Java 1.5 or 1.6... You are using 1.7

Install and use Java 1.5 or 1.6.